# 301 редирект в .htaccess не сработал

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Старый url товара
http://web-site.com/category1/tovar1.php
Новый url
http://web-site.com/category1/tovar1/
Код не сработал

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*).php(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Этот также не сработал

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)php(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^(category1|category2|category3|...)/([^/]+)\.php$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

1 группа захвата `(category1|category2|category3|...)` - перечисление всех категорий, иначе будет захватывать все обращения к файлам .php из подпапок первого уровня.

2 группа захвата `([^/]+)` имя файла, которое состоит как минимум из 1 символа и не содержит символ `/`.

Флаг `QSA` для передачи get переменных при редиректе.

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем подходит. Уже более 50 категорий + постоянный рост числа категорий.

Comment: @tomas_morgam, сколько у вас подпапок первого уровня, которые не относятся к категориям?